# Query influxdb for a date

Tags: influxdb

I have a table in influxdb that has a column called 'expirydate'. In the column I have afew dates e.g. "2016-07-14" or "2016-08-20". I want to select only the 2016-07-14 date, but I am unsure how?
My query is currently:

```
SELECT * FROM tablee where expirydate = '2016-07-14' limit 1000
```

But this does not work. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 14):

Assuming the value `table**e**` is a valid measurement...

If you are looking at selecting all of the points for the day '2016-07-14', then your query should look something like.

**Query:**

`SELECT * FROM tablee where time >= '2016-07-14 00:00:00' and time < '2016-07-15 00:00:00'`

You might also be interested in the influx's date time string in query.

**See**:
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.9/query_language/data_exploration/#relative-time

> **Date time strings**
>  Specify time with date time strings. Date time
>   strings can take two formats: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.nnnnnnnnn and
>   YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.nnnnnnnnnZ, where the second specification is
>   RFC3339. Nanoseconds (nnnnnnnnn) are optional in both formats.

**Note:**
The `limit` api could be redundant in your original query as it is there to impose restriction to the query from returning more than 1,000 point data.

Answer (score 1):

I had to force influx to treat my 'string date' as a string. This works:

```
SELECT * FROM tablee where expirydate=~ /2016-07-14/ limit 1000;
```

Comment: So the query suggested by me didn't work for you? Also, have you tried enquoting the string? Doing `=~ /.../~ means are running a regular expression. Just out of curiousity is `expirydate` actually a tag, I suppose you are not actually looking for a query by would filter by real  date... Assuming `expirydate` is a tag then a string match would have done the job.