# How to parse current time to InfluxDB Go client?

Tags: go, time, influxdb

I am using below Go client ("github.com/influxdata/influxdb/client/v2") to query InfluDB and it is working fine

```
q = fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE time > now() - 3600s", Measurement)
```

but I want to use Go time variable instead of InfluxDB **now()**

```
t := time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)
q = fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE time > %s - 3600s", Measurement, t)
```

but getting **error parsing query: found -01, expected ; at line 1, char 101**

Comment: You might want to calculate t - 3600s in Go and use that value in your query. Date/time in InfluxDB has its own format, surrounded by single quotes. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38299252/query-influxdb-for-a-date

Answer (score 2):

Date strings must be single quoted. Using

```
t := time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)
q = fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE time > '%s' - 3600s", Measurement, t)
```

Should solve your issue.